# sed Command removes "\"

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I'm trying to replace a text from a file with the text from another file. My issue is that the text from the initial file has multiple "\n" in it. The result of the command below is that all of the "\n" occurrences have the "\" removed from them.

```
sed -e "s@TEXT_TO_REPLACE@$(cat $replacementManager)@g" $file > $manager
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happens when you state the new text, rather than trying to pull it from a file?

Comment: It seems that sed has an issue with "\".

Comment: I'd see (GNU sed) `\n` replaced with new-lines, which is sort of expected. Perhaps you should really try to provide sample in-/output.